# how can i get some random value from dbpedia of some dbpedia property?

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I am working with dbpedia. I am parsing a dbpedia json file(for example http://dbpedia.org/data/Germany.json) and information. As I am new in this field, i have a question. In my work, I need to make a quiz game where the data will come from dbpedia. For example,

```
 the question what is the capital of Germany? ans:"Berlin"
```

I can make question and get the correct ans by parsing the dbpedia json file. But i need to make the options also as it will be multiple choice. So, My question is, How can I get those options from dbpedia? That means I need some other capital name from dbpedia (as a example).

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this, which returns four rows, each of which has the right answer (Berlin) and a wrong answer (something else that's a non-Berlin capital of some non-Germany resource):

```sql
select distinct ?rightAnswer ?wrongAnswer where {
  #-- get the capital of Germany
  dbr:Germany dbo:capital ?rightAnswer .

  #-- get the capitials of some other things, as
  #-- long as those things aren't Germany, and the 
  #-- capital isn't Berlin.
  ?s dbo:capital ?wrongAnswer .
  filter ( ?s != dbr:Germany && ?wrongAnswer != ?rightAnswer )
}
limit 4
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql/?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20distinct%20%3FrightAnswer%20%3FwrongAnswer%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%23--%20get%20the%20capital%20of%20Germany%0D%0A%20%20dbr%3AGermany%20dbo%3Acapital%20%3FrightAnswer%20.%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%23--%20get%20the%20capitials%20of%20some%20other%20things%2C%20as%0D%0A%20%20%23--%20long%20as%20those%20things%20aren%27t%20Germany%2C%20and%20the%20%0D%0A%20%20%23--%20capital%20isn%27t%20Berlin.%0D%0A%20%20%3Fs%20dbo%3Acapital%20%3FwrongAnswer%20.%0D%0A%20%20filter%20%28%20%3Fs%20!%3D%20dbr%3AGermany%20%26%26%20%3FwrongAnswer%20!%3D%20%3FrightAnswer%20%29%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Alimit%204%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on)